# How to include credentials in node request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, request, fetch

im trying to get array edges from this url 
`https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_id=17851374694183129&variables={"id":"500818047","first":10}

In the frontend, I can get this array with fetch and credentials: 'include'.
But I can't work with him because of CORS. So, **I try to do** this in `app.js` using node, but array is still hidden.
That's what I get:

```
{ 
   edge_followed_by:
   { 
     count: 18213,
     page_info: { has_next_page: false, end_cursor: null },
     edges: [] 
   } 
}
```

How to enable the parameter credentials in node request? Or, if I do something wrong, how to get this array?

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
var request = require("request");

const url = 'https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_id=17851374694183129&variables={"id":"500818047","first":10}';

request({
    url: url,
    json: true,
}, function (error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(body['data']['user'])
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when you hit the URL from frontend you may have already logged into Instagram so the `User Access Token` is present in your browser's cookies and hence you are able to access all the information in `edges`

[image]

[image]

Try the same thing after logging out of Instagram or try it with incognito mode and you would find that `edges` are empty because the browser no longer holds the `User Access Token` needed to check for permissions and provide you with the information.

[image]
[image]

To do it from a backend service follow the steps provided here,
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the [request docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#http-authentication)?

You have the following options to authenticate your request:

```js
request.get('http://some.server.com/').auth('username', 'password', false);
// or
request.get('http://some.server.com/', {
  'auth': {
    'user': 'username',
    'pass': 'password',
    'sendImmediately': false
  }
});
// or
request.get('http://some.server.com/').auth(null, null, true, 'bearerToken');
// or
request.get('http://some.server.com/', {
  'auth': {
    'bearer': 'bearerToken'
  }
});
```